# Использует ли мое приложение шифрование?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore

Пытаюсь загрузить приложение в TestFlight, приложение отправляет запрос на сервер по HTTPS, для получение базы слов. Также приложение отправляет в этом запросе один параметр это язык, в бушующем планируется добавить отправку UDID.

Comment: `HTTPS` подразумевает шифрование. Ответить на вопрос из вашего заголовка - невозможно, без анализ кода вашего приложения.

Comment: Обычный HTTPS запрос, используя URLSession.

Comment: HTTPS подразумевает шифрование. Если ваше приложение его использует и делает это правильно, значит трафик шифруется, если нет, значит нет. И это я скромно "умолчал" про возможные проблемы с сертификатам и прочим. Для ознакомления: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask